# how to get the most recent dataset using a wildcard in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

if I have a series of fact tables such as:

```
fact-01012001
fact-01022001
fact-01032001
dim001
dim002
```

a wildcard will allow me to search all three, for example:

```
select * from fact-*
```

is there a way to use wildcards or otherwise to get the most recent fact table? say only 01032001?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is **one-step** approach for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.fact_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN (
  SELECT 
    FORMAT_DATE('%m%d%Y', MAX(PARSE_DATE('%m%d%Y', SUBSTR(table_id, - 8)))) AS d
  FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
  WHERE SUBSTR(table_id, 1, LENGTH('fact_')) = 'fact_' 
  AND LENGTH(table_id) = LENGTH('fact_') + 8
  GROUP BY SUBSTR(table_id, 1, LENGTH(table_id) - 8)
)
```

Of course you can replace `LENGTH('fact_')` with `5` - I just put it this way so it is understood better
And `8` is the length of expected suffix, so you are catching only expected table from list of :

fact_01012001
fact_01022001
fact_01032001

Comment: That is brilliant.  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Until [the relevant feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36396950) is implemented, you will need to use a query to determine the most recent date, then another query to select from that table. For example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX AS latest_date
FROM `fact-*`
ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%m%d%Y', _TABLE_SUFFIX) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

After retrieving the latest date, query it:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `fact-01032001`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to improve one step further the solution given by [Mikhail Berlyant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45120363/1776630).

As the number of shards grow, you will see a couple of problems:

1. You are always querying all the shards, increasing the billing (BigQuery bills by the bytes processed by the query, more shards, more bytes).
2. There is a limit of 1000 shards that you can query in a single query (one shard per day is a bit under 3 years worth of data).

So, with this solution, you would be only be querying 1 or 2 shards, depending if the daily data have been already loaded or not.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.fact_*`
WHERE
PARSE_DATE('%m%d%Y',
_TABLE_SUFFIX) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND CURRENT_DATE()
  AND
_TABLE_SUFFIX IN (
  SELECT 
    FORMAT_DATE('%m%d%Y', MAX(PARSE_DATE('%m%d%Y', SUBSTR(table_id, - 8)))) AS d
  FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
  WHERE STARTS_WITH(table_id, 'fact_')
  AND LENGTH(table_id) = LENGTH('fact_') + 8
)
```

All the notes from the original answer applies.